# Cause of NZEC error for this program?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist, runtime-error

I have a problem where I need to find the second maximum element of the user inputs. It's an online practice problem and I can't figure out why the server responds back with NZEC error when I submit my code. Can someone tell me which part of my code is prone to such errors and how I can deal with this error?

```
Sample Input:=                Sample Output:=

2                             7
1 3 5 7 8 -1                  16
12 23 16 0 2 -1
```

P.S- The first input is the number of test cases. Second and third inputs are the actual user inputs respectively. And user inputs are always terminated with -1.

Here is my code:=

```
class SecondLargest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int testcase=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        while(testcase-->0){
            ArrayList<Long> al=new ArrayList<>();
            long num=0;
            long i=0;
            while((num=(sc.nextLong()))!=-1){
                al.add(num);
                i++;
            }
            Collections.sort(al);
            if(al.size()==0){
                System.err.println("");
            }
            else if(al.size()==1){
                System.out.println(al.get(0));
            }
            else if(al.size()>1){
            System.out.println(al.get((int)(al.size()-2)));
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

PSS- Large input sets will be used to test the program.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536374/runtime-error-nzec

Comment: The comment is absolutely invalid. I have seen your link and it has nothing to do with the above question.

Answer (score 0):

if you pass just one/zero element, then you will get index out of bound exception at line:

```
System.out.println(al.get((int)(i-2)));//negative scenario where you might be expected to return -1?
```

Comment: I have added two S.o.p for one/zero element along with the one mentioned above.But still it gives me an NZEC.

Comment: Update your code in question. Why are you using long? What range are you looking for?

Comment: There are no input constraints given for this problem. But if one of the elements is greater than int? There is no way to tell whether the values would always be in integer's range.

Answer (score 0):

```
    else if(al.size()==1){
      System.out.println(al.get(0));
    }
```

doesn't find the second maximum element, but the only element, which is the maximum element!

Change the if / elseif block to

```
    if(al.size()<2){
        System.err.println("");
    } else {
        System.out.println(al.get((int)(al.size()-2)));
    }
```